# How can I install redis server 7 on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, redis, snap

I'd like to install the newest `Redis Server 7` on my Ubuntu 22.04 (I've already installed Redis Server version 6 via standard workflow with `apt install`).

I tried to use a `Snap package` from https://snapcraft.io/redis

But my Redis is still version 6 and folder `/Snap/bin` looks like this (there is no `redis-server` command)

[image]

So it seems like Snap installation didn't replace existing Redis Server 6 installation.

Maybe I should go with some custom `ppa:` repository?

What I have to do in order to update Redis Server to version 7?

Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Updated answer (Aug 2022):**

Old answer works well, but now `snap` has Redis 7 (be careful, `redis.conf` is not in `/etc/redis/` anymore)

```
sudo snap install redis
```

**Original answer:**

[instructions](https://redis.io/docs/getting-started/installation/install-redis-on-linux/)

[repo](https://launchpad.net/%7Eredislabs/+archive/ubuntu/redis)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:redislabs/redis

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install redis
```

Comment: actually I would be reluctant pulling from [this ppa](https://launchpad.net/~redislabs/+archive/ubuntu/redis) since the source is not the same as the one on the [redis website](https://redis.io/docs/getting-started/installation/install-redis-on-linux/)

Answer (score 3):

There is now an official Redis repo: https://redis.io/docs/install/install-redis/install-redis-on-linux/

From that page:

```
curl -fsSL https://packages.redis.io/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/redis-archive-keyring.gpg

echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/redis-archive-keyring.gpg] https://packages.redis.io/deb $(lsb_release -cs) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/redis.list

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install redis
```